# What type of literary device is this?

Tags: literary-device

What literary term is applicable to  "I can see pain in your eyes."

Comment: Looks like a sentence to me.

Comment: usage of "see" is figurative or metaphorical.

Comment: Why has this been downvoted? It's a reasonable question.

Comment: @Mike Because it is incredibly vague and unclear. There are dozens of potential terms which would apply to the sentence. The question needs to be edited to make clear exactly what they're asking about.

Comment: Obviously pain can't be seen. Furthermore, eyes are not a medical instrument for assessing pain. There are literary devices in use within this phrase. What are they? It's a reasonable question.

Comment: @Mike How do you know that's what the OP was asking about?

Comment: Because it's a 7-word phrase; not much guess-work required. What else could the OP be referring to? If you want to give a smart-aleck response like "sentence", then so be it. But there are legitimate literary devices at play in that phrase.

Comment: @LittleEva - There's a good chance that "pain in your eyes" is metaphorical, too – unless the speaker happens to be an ophthalmologist. This could be referring to a look of sorrow on someone's face.

Comment: What is a "literary device"?

Comment: Speaking strictly for myself, I don't hold a brand-new user to the same standards of an established user, and so I don't downvote their OPs or answers, unless they're intentionally offensive. I try to educate rather then punish. That's how I was handled, for the most part, and I really appreciate that. I probably wouldn't still be here, otherwise. I try to "pay it forward."

Comment: Sweep http://literary-devices.com/

Comment: @LittleEva Sure, I try not to punish new users too. But unclear questions need to be closed no matter who asks them.

Comment: I'm with @LittleEva on this.  If it's a question that really should be on another site, usually Learners, it's fine to re-direct politely.  But this question belongs here, and deserves polite consideration.

Comment: @Blessed Geek, a literary device is an instrument of torture made with a combination of zeugma and bathos.

Comment: @curiousdannii - I was responding to your reply to Mike's question above, "Why has this been downvoted?" The OP would surely benefit from the inclusion of research. Many new users need "hands-on" guidance, or need to be directed toward the ELU tour. I try to be gentle with "newbies" (being barely out of swaddling clothes, myself). The site can be intimidating and new users vulnerable. They also suffer from an extreme "want" of rep points & privileges. Even when it is apparent that the newbie would be better served at our sister-site that transition can be handled with magnanimity. :-)

Comment: @curiousdannii - RE: *But unclear questions need to be closed no matter who asks them.* Actually, I'd rephrase that a little bit: _Unclear questions should be closed **or improved** no matter who asks them_. In my mind, clarification is preferred over closure.

Comment: @J.R. Of course. But for new users often being put on hold is the best way to get their attention to improve it. This OP for instance hasn't commented at all on this page since asking the question. All the answerers must be mindreaders because there are so many things the OP could be referring to.

Comment: @curiousdannii - We are in agreement. That said, sometimes an SE regular will say "should be closed" when they really mean to say "should be put on hold until we get additional information." Us veterans know what's trying to be said, but newcomers can read that "should be closed" and be put off by apparent rudeness.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Little Eva's answer, but I'll add one more thing:

The expression could be taken as an example (though perhaps not a perfect one) of a literary device called Synecdoche.

Synecdoche is when you use part of something to refer to the whole.

> "I can see pain in your eyes."

When I say I can see pain in your eyes, I mean I see the signs of emotional pain not in your literal eyeballs, but in your whole aspect (the muscles around your eyes, your forehead, your mouth, even your posture).

Answer (score 1):

```
          What literary term is applicable to "I can see pain in your eyes."
```

As far as literary devices, all that I can "*see*" in the given sentence is the figurative or metaphorical usage of "*see*" to represent the "*perception*," not of pain, per se, but of the symptoms or signs of either physical pain or emotional distress evident in another's eyes.

Comment: Agreed. Even then though, "perceive", or "understand the communicated concept" is a perfectly normal definition for "see". (eg: "I see what you are saying"). So you can say that this is using one of the more metaphorical definitions of "see", but calling it a full-blown literary device is a bit much.

Comment: @T.E.D. - Indeed, the figure of speech has become the default description, yet the usage remains, at root, metaphorical. Agreed, referring to common speech as a "literary device"? rather stretches the meaning of such "devices" to the breaking point, but there you have it.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add something to William Bloom's comprehensive explanation.

It may also refer to ***'cause for effect'*** or '***effect for cause***'. Here **pain** is the **cause** and the **effect** is **tears**. The writer may have referred to the **tears** but used the **cause** i.e. ***'pain'***.